# Derivative of a matrix valued function involving Hadamard product and SVD

Tags: real-analysis, matrix-calculus, svd, jacobian, hadamard-product

Consider a map $f:\mathcal{V}_m(\mathbb{R}^n)\times\mathbb{R}^m\times \mathcal{O}(m)\to \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ given by:
$$f(U,D,V)=A\circ UDV^T+UDV^T,$$ where $U^TU=I_m$, $V^TV=I_m$, $D$ is a diagonal matrix of singular values, $A$ is a fixed $n\times m$ matrix with entries 0 and 1, and $\circ$ denotes the Hadamard product of two matrices. Given that the map is totally differentiable, what is its Jacobian?

Comment: Let $J$ be the all-ones matrix and $B=(A+J).\;$
Then the equation becomes
$$\eqalign{
F &= f(U,S,V)  &= B\odot(USV^T) \\
G &= \;F\oslash B &= USV^T \\
}$$
Now the question is about the Jacobian of $G$ with respect to its SVD factors, which is the topic of several papers, like [this one](https://inria.hal.science/inria-00072686/document).

Comment: Is there a closed form relationship between the jacobians of F and G, in terms of det(B) perhaps?